# Correct plugin for Grails

Tags: grails, plugins, classmate

I am new to Grails, so I apologize for the newbie question.

I am trying to move an application to 2.4.3 from 1.3.7 and I hit this plugin - classmate-1.1.0. I have set the entry in my BuildConfig.grrovy file to be:

runtime 'com.fasterxml:classmate:1.1.0'

however, while I can locate the .jar file at:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0

, I can't seem to find the .zip file. This surprises me as I would have expected 'runtime' to require only the jar (as opposed to 'compile')

Can someone either tell me where to get the correct zip file, or explain to me why the framework wants to have the .zip file.

Thanks,

Stan

Comment: That wouldn't be a `plugin` but rather a `dependancy` in the `dependencies` section of your `BuildConfig.groovy`

Comment: Paste your config of `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`.

Comment: Joshua,

Thanks. Now that you state the obvious, it seems - well, obvious. I appreciate the help.

Stan